# Profiling the same C function called with different arguments

Tags: c, profiling, gprof

Some confusion using a profiler while working on a fixed-point DSP code.

When I run `gprof` on the following code:

```
main()
{
    ...
    g_apply(  &g_mono, in_mono  );
    g_apply(  &g_stereo, in_stereo  );
    ...
}
```

I get (self cycles, children cycles, function name):

```
16943.80, 4760.06 g_apply
```

But I wanted to see separate cycles for mono and stereo, so I did this:

```
void g_apply_mono(g* g_mono, in* in_mono)
{
    g_apply( g_mono, in_mono );
}
void g_apply_stereo(g* g_stereo, in* in_stereo)
{
    g_apply( g_stereo, in_stereo );
}    
main()
{
    ...
    g_apply_mono  ( &g_mono  , in_mono   );
    g_apply_stereo( &g_stereo, in_stereo );
    ...
}
```

However, profiler gives exactly the same cycles for both `g_apply_mono()` and `g_apply_stereo()`!

```
12.03 10851.93 g616_apply_mono
12.03 10851.93 g616_apply_stereo
```

What did I do wrong? Is there something that confuses the profiler?

Stereo is clearly much slower than mono, i.e. needs much more cycles.

The outputs in both above cases are the same, so the code is OK.

Comment: you could try to do _nothing_ in one of the methods and retry. see if the timings are the same.

Comment: Tried it and no, timings are not the same anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I never use gprof for profiling. As far as I remember, there was some controversy on whether it should be used for that purpose (I think it was designed with other goals in mind).

However, if you are interested in measuring cycles, you could use:

```
clock_t start = clock();

g_apply_mono  ( &g_mono  , in_mono   );

fprintf(stdout, "Clocks elapsed: %d\n", (int) (clock() - start));
```

Remember to include  in your headers. Also, if you are interested in measuring time you can just divide the number of clocks by the number of clocks in a second, i.e. CLOCKS_PER_SEC.